# Bivariate normal PDF

Tags: probability

Suppose that X & Y are bivariate normally distributed with

E(X)=2, Var(X)=9, E(Y)=1, Var(Y)=16, & p=.25

Determine P(X<3.5) & P(X<3.5 | Y =2)

---

The only mention of bivariate normal p.d.f. in my book is brief. It shows an equation and says that this joint p.d.f. is called a bivariate normal p.d.f. That doesn't help me understand what is going on at all! Can someone explain what it is or how to begin solving (even with different numbers)?

Comment: You may find this helpful http://www.aos.wisc.edu/~dvimont/aos575/Handouts/bivariate_notes.pdf

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't think that is $p$, I think it must be $\rho$, i.e. the correlation coefficient.

When $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal, each of them is normal on its own, $X \sim N(E(X),Var(X))$. So here we have $X \sim N(2,3^2)$, Now it is not difficult to find $P(X<3.5)$

Also when $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal, their conditional probability is also normal i.e. $P(X|Y=y_0) \sim N(\dots,\dots)$. It can be [proved](http://stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring12/sta104.1/Lectures/Lec22.pdf) that:
 $E[X|Y=y_0]=E[X]+\rho\sqrt{Var[X]}\left(\frac{y_0-E[Y]}{\sqrt{Var[Y]}}\right) \\ Var[X|Y=y_0]=Var[X](1-\rho^2)$

So $P(X|Y=2) \sim N(2.1875,6.75)$. Now you can calculate $P(X<3.5 | Y =2)$